# Получение объекта через клик - unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

делаю игру на unity. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы перменная gameobject target была равна объекту, на который мы нажали. Многие делают это с помощью event triger, но это сплошной геморой. Можно ли получить объект по клику без event triger, и с какой функцией?

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так:

```
GameObject target;

void Update()
{
 if( Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )
 {
     Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay( Input.mousePosition );
     RaycastHit hit;

     if( Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit, 100 ) )
     {
         target = transform.gameObject;
     };
 }
}
```